# Is this behaviour, unique to chrome, odd or the proper outcome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, attr

Found an oddity involving jquery and chrome.  Seems attr('width') for an img element returns 0 if the display of the surrounding div is set to "none".  This works fine in firefox and opera though.

So, is this a bug or is chrome asserting the correct jquery behaviour?

Here's an example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="return.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="foot">
  <img src="images/ref.png" width="500px" height="500px"  />
  <img src="images/ref1.png" width="300px" height="300px"  />
</div>

</body>
</html>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('div.foot').css('display','none');

var imageWidth = $('div.foot img').eq(0).attr('width');

alert(imageWidth); // returns 0 in chrome.

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be a Chrome bug.

First, I ran your code as above. It displayed "0" as you described.

Then, I played around with the above code, and was able to have the width (500) display in the dev console with the following code:

```
$('div.foot img').eq(0).attr('width');
```

So, I re-wrote the original code you have to something slightly smaller. This displayed "500" as expected:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.foot').css('display','none');
    alert($('div.foot img').eq(0).attr('width'));
});
```

After that, I was able to run your original code and have it alert "500".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.foot').css('display','none');
    var imageWidth = $('div.foot img').eq(0).attr('width');
    alert(imageWidth); // returns 0 in chrome.
});
```

Short answer: I'm pretty sure this is a bug because of its erratic behaviour.

**Note:** I tried this using jQuery 1.4.4.

Answer (score 1):

Images are displayed as `inline` and doesnt give width/height when parent is hidden (in Chrome).

Set your images to `display:block;` and Chrome will you your width/height. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/c4jdv/